# Where are the Linux paste buffers managed

Tags: linux, copy-paste

On standard Linux setups you have two general paste buffers, the main copy(<kbd>^C</kbd>)/paste(<kbd>^V</kbd>) one and the select-text/middle-click one.
For both of these buffers:

- At what level in the environment are these buffers stored/managed; the kernel, the X server, KDE/Gnome, or some other service somewhere?
- Can they be programmatically accessed somehow using some standard library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're at [the X level](http://tronche.com/gui/x/icccm/sec-2.html) ([simplified description](http://standards.freedesktop.org/clipboards-spec/clipboards-latest.txt)). They can be accessed via normal X routines.